# Simultaneously setState and Change Scene

Tags: react-native

This is more of a performance/best practice question.

I currently have a child component that needs to alter state of it's parent and run an AJAX request on the parent.  When the TouchableHighlight is pressed, the child scene needs to change back and the parent state needs to change/execute ajax request.

I'm using React Native Router Flux for my navigation.

Is the best way to accomplish this to pass the needed state changes through props back to the parent e.g. Actions.feed({foo:bar}) ?

Or can I pass a parent method through to the child via props and execute that from the child?  That method would update the parents state.

The problem I'm having with that approach is that I cannot alter the parent state and change scenes at the same time as the parent is still mounting and you cannot setState on a mounting component.  Is there someway to do this with a Promise from the parent method that can be returned once the setState has completed at which point I can change Scene?  Not sure how to do this or even if it's the best method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general practice is to provide a callback to the child component. For ex:

```
export default class Child extends Component{
   render(){
       return (<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onItemClicked}>
          ....
       </TouchableHighlight>);
}

export default class Parent extends Component{
.....
    onItemClicked(){
      //ajax request, set state
    }
}
```

An improvement over this would be fire off a Flux action. You can do that in the child component if you don't intend to make it reusable or if you want it to be reusable fire off flux action in the parent component callback.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll use the method approach.